# Advanced slicing: Given a list of index, pick different elements from a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, slice

I am implementing a decision making algorithm. In the `daily_choices` array, there are two fruits to choose every single day, for example:

```
daily_choices = np.array([['apple','orange'],['strawberry','orange'],['watermelon','apple']])
```

Now I have a list containing the fruit that I am going to choose every single day:

```
decision = [0,1,0]
```

I know some basic slicing, such as `daily_choices[:,0]`, which meaning slicing the first column out, and `daily_choices[:,1]` means slicing the second column out.

I wonder if there's anyway to slice the first column in first row, second column in second row, first column in third row by doing something like the following

### Expected result

```
Input  =>  daily_choices[:,[0,1,0]]
Output =>  ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon']
```

Yet, it doesn't give me the desired result

I know I can achieve the my desired result by using `zip` and for `loop`

```
daily_decision
daily_decision = []
for choices, index in zip(daily_choices, decision):
    daily_decision.append(choices[index])
daily_decision
```

But I want to know if it is possible to do it in one line.

Comment: use `daily_decision = [choices[index] for choices, index in zip(daily_choices, decision)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using list comprehension

```
choices = [['apple', 'orange'], ['strawberry', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'apple']]
decisions = [0, 1, 0] 

daily_decisions = [day[decision] for day, decision in zip(choices, decision)]
print(daily_decisions)
```

> ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon']

### Using numpy

This can be also solved with [NumPys Integer Array Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
import numpy as np
daily_choices = np.array([['apple','orange'],['strawberry','orange'],['watermelon','apple']])
decisions = [0, 1, 0]

daily_decision = daily_choices[range(len(daily_choices)), decisions]
print(daily_decision)
```

> ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon']

Answer (score 1):

Using purely `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

daily_choices = np.array([['apple', 'orange'],['strawberry', 'orange'],['watermelon', 'apple']])
decision = np.array([0, 1, 0])

n_fruits = 2

fruit_range = np.reshape(np.arange(n_fruits), (-1, n_fruits))
indices = np.reshape(decision, (len(decision), 1)) == fruit_range

daily_choices[indices]
```

Output:

```
array(['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'], dtype='<U10')
```